# get ng-model value of span on ng-click in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
I want to achieve that to get cityName whenever I clicked on city name.
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

> http://plnkr.co/edit/Vb9akn0Qx8ZhTDQxOIoy?p=preview

Comment: Please don't 'cheat' the system by putting the text as code. Put the code in the post body and you still can provide the plunker as a help

Comment: This would be a good time to take a few minutes and read [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is you code updated.

I have passed cityName  to function and assigned it to name variable you want to show.
Also I fixed part of code where you calling weather api to use selected city in query.

Hope it help.

[`Plnkr Working example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/cwKmOKRKFubbhKTUsGAg?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks kadir.

Comment: Consider adding the essential part to your answer instead of providing just the plunker

Comment: @user9852397 Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value into your function, like so:

```
$scope.weatherUpdate = function(cityName) {
```

And change the HTML file, like so:

```
<li ng-click="weatherUpdate(x.cityName)" ng-repeat="x in cities">
```

This way, you can use the `cityName` variable within your `weatherUpdate` function

Answer (score 0):

you should pass 'x.cityName' instead of 'cityName' in to the ng-click function.

```
<li ng-click="weatherUpdate(x.cityName)" ng-repeat="x in cities">
  <span ng-model="cityName">{{x.cityName}}</span>
</li>
```